# Flot time plotting

Tags: javascript, jquery, time-series, flot, bar-chart

I'm trying to create a stacked barchart using flot. I have my data as

```
var data = [{
        "data": [[1336979060, 0], [1339605620, 0], [1342232180, 0], [1344858740, 0], [1347485300, 0], [1350111860, 2]],
        "label": "1 months"},
    {
        "data": [[1336979060, 0], [1339605620, 0], [1342232180, 0], [1344858740, 0], [1347485300, 0], [1350111860, 1]],
        "label": "2 months"},
    {
        "data": [[1336979060, 0], [1339605620, 0], [1342232180, 0], [1344858740, 0], [1347485300, 0], [1350111860, 1]],
        "label": "3 months"},
    {
        "data": [[1336979060, 0], [1339605620, 0], [1342232180, 0], [1344858740, 0], [1347485300, 0], [1350111860, 0]],
        "label": "4 months"},
    {
        "data": [[1336979060, 0], [1339605620, 0], [1342232180, 0], [1344858740, 0], [1347485300, 0], [1350111860, 0]],
        "label": "5 months"},
    {
        "data": [[1336979060, 0], [1339605620, 0], [1342232180, 0], [1344858740, 0], [1347485300, 0], [1350111860, 0]],
        "label": "6 months"},
    {
        "data": [[1336979060, 0], [1339605620, 0], [1342232180, 0], [1344858740, 0], [1347485300, 0], [1350111860, 1]],
        "label": "7 months"}];
```

I have created a fiddle to help you understand it better: http://jsfiddle.net/julijan/g2aJV/4/

You can see that it renders the labels correctly and it even renders the months correctly, which means it understands the data, but the bars are not showing.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Julijan

Comment: Did you check that your datatime values are inside the max and min valued of your x axis?

Comment: Damn! That was the problem, needed to multiply the x values by 1000 to convert to milliseconds. Now it works but there is another problem, the bar is about 1 pixel thick http://jsfiddle.net/julijan/g2aJV/6/ it kind of makes sense, all x values are at the same second, but I would like my bar to span over the whole month.

Comment: Solved it, had to set the bar width to the appropriate number of miliseconds, 30.4 days in my case. Thanks VicoMan! Here is the final fiddle in case someone has a similar problem: http://jsfiddle.net/julijan/g2aJV/7/

Comment: Julijan, you should post your fix as an answer to your own question, then mark it as the answer, this makes it easier for somebody to troubleshoot when they have a similar problem and run into this post... one day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the problem make sure your x values are in the range of min-max you've defined. If you are using an unix timestamp make sure you multiply it by 1000 to convert seconds to milliseconds.